# The Divergence Criteria for Sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I know that if two subsequences $X'$ and $X''$ of the sequence $X$ converge to two different limits, then the sequence X is divergent.

If $X$ is $(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...)$ where the first three terms are $0$ and all other terms are 1. If I divide $X$ into two subsequences:

- $X' = (0, 0, 0) $
- $X'' = (1, 1, 1, 1, ...)$

The two subsequences have limits $0$ and $1$ respectively. So, according to the divergence criteria for sequences, the sequence $X$ diverges and has no limit. But this should not be the case as $X$ obviously converges to $1$.

I am wondering where I make things wrong.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Look again at the definition of a subsequence; it ought to be a sequence! That is, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ you must get an $x_n$. Your $X'$ only has $x_1,x_2,x_3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly note that it is better to state the following:

- if two subsequences $X'$ and $X''$ of the sequence $X$ converge to two different limits, then the sequence $X$ $\color{red}{\text{has not limit}}$.

Secondly when we deal with sequences and subsequences to study convergence we are interested to the their values when $n \to \infty$.

Therefore $X'=(0,0,0)$ is not a subsequence.

Indeed, for any given a sequence $X_n:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{R}$ a subsequence is any $X_{i_n}$ with $i_n$ an increasing sequence of natuaral numbers.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @ancientmathematician , the rule holds when you define "subsequence" as an infinite sequence.

So to reword the rule to help you remember that, it should be " if two infinite subsequences X' and X'' of the infinite sequence X converge to two different limits, then the sequence X is divergent. "